# php xpath evaluate duplicate data get only first row

Tags: php, xpath, evaluate

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",1);

ini_set('max_execution_time', 36000); //300 seconds = 5 minutes

$url = 'http://www.sportstats.com/soccer/matches/20170815/';

libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);


$data = array(

'HomeTeam' => $xpath->evaluate('string(//td[@class="table-home"]/a)'),
'AwayTeam' => $xpath->evaluate('string(//td[contains(@class, "table-away")]/a)'),
'FtScore' => $xpath->evaluate('string(normalize-space(translate(//td[@class="result-neutral"]," " ,"")))'),
'HomeTeamid' => $xpath->evaluate('substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(//td[@class="table-home"]/a/@href, "/soccer/"),"-"),"/")'),
'AwayTeamid' => $xpath->evaluate('substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(//td[@class="table-away"]/a/@href, "/soccer/"),"-"),"/")')

);

foreach ($data as $key) {

echo $data['HomeTeamid'].",";
echo $data['HomeTeam'].",";
echo $data['FtScore'].",";
echo $data['AwayTeam'].",";
echo $data['AwayTeamid']."<br/>";

}

?>
```

But the script gives duplicate results:

```
n3QdnjFB,Santos,0-0,Fluminense,EV9L3kU4
n3QdnjFB,Santos,0-0,Fluminense,EV9L3kU4
n3QdnjFB,Santos,0-0,Fluminense,EV9L3kU4
n3QdnjFB,Santos,0-0,Fluminense,EV9L3kU4
n3QdnjFB,Santos,0-0,Fluminense,EV9L3kU4
```

But I want it's look like...

```
 HTeamid,Santos,0-0,Fluminense,ATeamid
 HTeamid,Cartagena,1-0,Llaneros,ATeamid
 HTeamid,Cerro Porteno,1-1,Libertad Asuncion,ATeamid
 HTeamid,Operario,2-1,Maranhao,ATeamid
 HTeamid,Emelec,2-0,Fuerza,ATeamid
 ...
 ..
 .
```

[Matches list image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRYfq.png)
I looked at other questions on the site and didn"t find an answer
How do i do get all other teams data with echo command (I don't want to do with var_dump). Thanks.

Comment: Can you also show us the expected result?

Comment: [Matches list on website][1]
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRYfq.png

Comment: Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: I don't know PHP so I can't help

Answer (score 0):

Here are two mistakes, you use `//td` in the location path. This makes the path relative to the document and the string function always return the text content of the first node in the list. You get always the first game.

The typical structure for fetching list data is:

```
foreach($xpath->evaluate($exprForItems) as $item) {
  $detail = $xpath->evaluate($exprForDetail, $item);
}
```

A more specific example:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$expressions = new stdClass();
// this is the expression for items - it returns a node list
$expressions->games = '//div[@id = "LS_todayMatchesContent"]/table/tbody/tr';
// this are detail expressions - they return a string
$expressions->home = 'string(td[@class = "table-home"]/a)';
$expressions->homeId = 'substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(td[@class="table-home"]/a/@href, "/soccer/"),"-"),"/")';
$expressions->away= 'string(td[@class = "table-away"]/a)';

foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expressions->games) as $game) {
  var_dump(
    [
      $xpath->evaluate($expressions->home, $game),
      $xpath->evaluate($expressions->homeId, $game),
      $xpath->evaluate($expressions->away, $game)
    ]
  );
}
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Santos"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "n3QdnjFB"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "Fluminense"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "Cartagena"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "6eofBSjQ"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "Llaneros"
}
//...
```

So only the detail expressions use the string functions and they always need the item node as the context (second argument). You have to be careful to use the context.

Comment: Empty screen. I didn't get any result.

Comment: It does not have to be?      $html = file_get_contents('http://www.sportstats.com/soccer/matches/');     Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID todayMatches_0 already defined in Entity, line: 133 in

Comment: That is not part of the Xpath logic, but the HTML loading. You will need to capture/hide the errors like you did in your question. And yes, the HTML is broken it has duplicate id attributes.

Comment: Ok, I'il try my best. I don't keep you busy anymore. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Try edit your xpath array like this:

```
'HomeTeam' => $xpath->query('//td[@class="table-home"]/a'),
'AwayTeam' => $xpath->query('//td[contains(@class, "table-away")]/a'),
'FtScore' => $xpath->query('//td[@class="result-neutral"]'),
...
```

using `query` and altering paths.

And then you can echo your results like this:

```
foreach ($data as $dataKey => $dataValue) {
    foreach ($dataValue as $key => $element) {
        $nodes = $element->childNodes;  
        foreach ($nodes as $node) { 
            $tag = $node->nodeValue;
            echo $dataKey.' - '.$key.' - '.$tag.'<br>';  //$dataKey and $key are just informative
        }
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

For me, it listed:

```
HomeTeam - 0 - Santos
HomeTeam - 1 - Cartagena
HomeTeam - 2 - Cerro Porteno
HomeTeam - 3 - Operario
HomeTeam - 4 - Boca Juniors
HomeTeam - 5 - Emelec
....
AwayTeam - 0 - Fluminense
AwayTeam - 1 - Llaneros
AwayTeam - 2 - Libertad Asuncion
AwayTeam - 3 - Maranhao
AwayTeam - 4 - Gimnasia y Tiro
AwayTeam - 5 - Fuerza A.
....
```

Of course, if you want some meaningful print of data, you need it to collect in array....

Hope this is the answer you are looking for :) 
Have a great day!

Comment: This is not what I want. xpath-query not support string ,substring-before-after function. You can't do this features with the xpath-query. Must use xpath-evaluate for hometeamid and awayteamid...as much as I know. thank you anyway. Have a great day.

Comment: `DOMXpath::query()` is a limited variant of `DOMXpath::evaluate()` given the same expression evaluate() will return the same node list.

Comment: What to do for this question ? is there any solution ?